# On a real line R points a,b are randomly selected such that -2<=a<=2 and 0<=b<=3. Find the probability that | a - b | > 1

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let's say that C is the set where |a-b|>1

So I suppose you could say plot it as coordinates where the x-axis (labelled a) is from [-2,2] and the y-axis (labelled b) is from [0,3].

Now |a-b| must be greater than 1

|2-3| = 1

|2-2| = 0

|2-1| = 1

...

these are not in the set C

|2-0| = 2

|1-3| = 2

|0-3| = 3

|0-2| = 2

|-1-3| = 4

|-1-2| = 3

|-1-1| = 2

|-2-3| = 5

|-2-2| = 4

|-2-1| = 3

|-2-0| = 2

C = { (2,0) ; (1,3) ; (0,3) ; (0,2) ; (-1,3); (-1,2); (-1,1) ; (-2,3) ; (-2, 2) ; (-2,1); (-2,0) }

n(C) = 11

n(S) = 4 x 5

```
 = 20
```

P(C) = n(C) / n(S)

```
 = 11/20

 = 0.55
```

Is this right. Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track: draw a rectangle with $-2<a<2 ; 0<b<3$ , on $a-b$- axes and draw the lines $a-b$=1 (associated to $x-y>1$ , and then $b-a=1$ associated to $y-x>-1$, and look at the region/subset of the rectangle where the conditions are satisfied. Calculate the area of this region and then divide by the total area of the rectangle.

Comment: Oh thanks. I knew I was missing something :)

Comment: Got the same answer of course but an easier way of seeing it. Yeah. There's an are where it does not have any in the set but everywhere else you just count the points. Wait. It is correct to use the individual points right?

Comment: @user157220: you usually count just the area inside of the rectangle; I just got an outside look at the same issue. Don't worry about the outside individual points.